# Php imap_mail email bounce back if email address not in address book

Tags: php, email, imap

I am using imap_mail to send the emails.

We have came across the case when user has typed email address in upper case. For example email address is test@test.com and user typed Test@test.com.

### We get following bounce back message

From: Mail Delivery System [mailto:MAILER-DAEMON@xxxxx.example.com]
To: Test
Subject: Undeliverable: subject text

Your message did not reach some or all of the intended recipients.

```
  Subject:  subject text
  Sent:     9/4/2013 1:25 PM
```

The following recipient(s) cannot be reached:

```
  Test on 9/4/2013 1:25 PM
        The e-mail account does not exist at the organization this message was sent to.
        Check the e-mail address, or contact the recipient directly to find out the correct address.
        < #5.1.1 X-Postfix; unknown user: "Test">
```

Comment: Yes, this is expected behaviour: email addresses are actually case sensitive.  What is your issue, and what is it you think you should change?  There is no question here.

Comment: If email is cases sensitive then is there any function where I can cross check. So that I can prompt to the user as email address is incorrect

Comment: In general, the only way to check if an email address is valid is to send email to it.

Comment: Seeing whether you have mail from a particular address is a fairly good check.